# raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed") smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: django

I use Django and every time when I try to send an email I get this response

```
Internal Server Error: /order/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\Desktop\Admin\py\qazpoligrah1\main\views.py", line 53, in post
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 91, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 432, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\Daniil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

my settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

my views.py

```
def post(self,request):
    print(request.POST.get('mail'), request.POST.get('type'))
    prod_type = models.ProductTypes.objects.filter(pk = 
    request.POST.get('type'))
    order_msg = prod_type[0].name
    email = EmailMessage('Qazpoligraph', order_msg, 
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to= (request.POST.get('mail'),))
    email.send()
    return redirect('/')
```

I tried to change the EMAIL_PORT and the EMAIL_HOST but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. I've solved my problem. I think it may be helpful for another people who ran into such a type of this problem
The problem was in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yourmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

I studied smtplib where port is filled automatically. Then I dropted "EMAIL_BACKEND " and after made a decision to drop port in settings. Fortunately it works after that. Finally I have two working scripts which can send email messages(smtplib and django)

Comment: I studied smtplib where port is filled automatically. Then I dropted "EMAIL_BACKEND " and after made a decision to drop port in settings. Fortunately it works after that. Finally I have two working scripts which can send email messages(smtplib and django)